# How to add packages into .exe file using py2exe?

Tags: python, py2exe

I have an app with two packages..

My setup.py is like this:

```
sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    windows = [{'script': "SoundLog.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

After creating the .exe I have to put the packages in the same folder as the .exe file.

How can I include them in the .exe?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks like the right options to me.  Are you sure they're not in the exe?  What error message do you get?

Comment: I'll tell you later on when I arrive home.
Using "from x import *" or "import y from x" is different in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for .py files in a folder to see how many there were in the code.
That was why I needed that folder!

The code that I presented in the question is correct!